# How to find corners / vertices of Polyhedron

Tags: optimization

Polyhedron $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, given by the inequalities:
$x_1+2x_2\geq 1,\qquad x_1\geq -1,\qquad x_1-x_2\geq -3,\qquad x_2\geq 1,\qquad -2x_1-x_2\leq 0  $
Giving matrix $A$ and vector $b$, such that $Ax\leq b$:
$$
   A= \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & -2\\
    -1 & 0\\
    -1 & 1\\
     0 & -1\\
-2&-1
    \end{pmatrix}\qquad,\qquad b=\begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    1\\
    3\\
-1\\
0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

How do I proceed to find the corners/vertices of $\mathcal{P}$ ? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $x_1+2x_2=1$ splits the $(x_1,x_2)$-plane into two halfplanes. In one of these we have $x_1+2x_2\geq1$. Draw the line on graphed paper, and mark the "good side" with an arrow $\nearrow$ standing orthogonally on the line, or similar. Do this for each of the five conditions. The set ${\cal P}$ consists of all the points that are on the "good side" of every drawn line. You will have to compute some intersection points.